# How to trigger gitlab ci when a comment like "test please" is written in merge request discussion?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I saw there are several ways to trigger the CI.

Even for merge requests
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/

What I want to do is to trigger a gitlab CI pipeline not for all merge request and not for all commits. 
Only when someone comments:

'test please' or 'test gitlab' or some special keyword maybe defined by regex?

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

That was requested in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` issue 39215](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/39215), and shipped with 11.0

```
rspec:
  script: ...
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /some-regexp/
```

You also have the following workaround for pipelines (windows cmd shell):

> Process the job only if commit message doesn't contain [CI Release]

```
script:
        - git show -s --format=%%B | findstr /C:"[CI Release]" >nul 2>&1 && (exit 0) || (set errorlevel=0)
        - cd beUcb
        - call mvn -N -Pver resources:resources
        - REM ... rest of script ...
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough. I mean comments in merge requests not in commits. Is there a way to trigger a job when someone in merge request comments somethine like "test please"?

Comment: @nacho4d Not sure, considering https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/23902 is still opened. I was going with the latest commit message of the branch being merged.